# Spring defaultHtmlEscape doesn't prevent xss attack

Tags: spring, xss

I want to prevent xss attacks in my spring application.

I added

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

into my web.xml (I found this soulution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2147958/2674303))

but on my page I save content with name `<script>alert(1);</script>` and this scripts executes after page refresh.

client side code:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'setContentName',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {contentId: id, name: params.value}
});
```

What do I wrong?

### P.S.

I load content using javascript after refresh

Comment: That property will only influence the use of the spring form tags it will not be a general purpose solution.

Comment: hm. Can you advise something more general?

Comment: Google will give you several solutions...

Comment: I think this is true by default. See if this answer help you see what's wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147958/how-do-i-prevent-people-from-doing-xss-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Mine is a somewhat controversial opinion, but I think you should validate and reject inbound XSS. You should escape it on output too, but it shouldn't be in your database in the first place, as dbs are long-lasting and often cross-application.

See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_JSON_Sanitizer

Use Hibernate Validator (you don't need to use Hibernate ORM) with JSoup to avoid XSS in your db:

`Foo.java`:

```
@Entity
class Foo {

  @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE)
  private String name;

  ...
}
```

`FooController.java`:

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

  @RequestMapping(method=POST)
  String submit(@Validated Foo foo) {
     ...
  }

}
```

`pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

See [Adding additonal Security to Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012109/adding-additonal-security-to-website/29015666#29015666) for more anti-XSS measures

Answer (score -1):

I use JSTL for the purpose. Include c prefix in the jsp page,

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>`

For the value you want to show

`<c:out value=${someVar} escapeXml="true" />`

Setting the attribute `excapeXml="true"` is optional in this scenario because its default value is true

[Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html)

Comment: This doesn't prevent XSS attack content winding up in your DB, which op's attempt does at least attempt to accomplish.  As such I feel this is an incomplete and potentially misleading/dangerous answer.