# Is it possible to send a token per request in Spring Security (CSRF `Synchronizer Token Pattern`)?

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

I have a single page application on Spring. And I want to protect the app from CSRF attacks.

Is it possible to send a token per request in Spring Security (CSRF `Synchronizer Token Pattern`)?

And does Spring support such feature?

Comment: Why do you want token per request over token per session? Have you considered the implications on caching?

Comment: Because I fire multiples requests via Ajax without page reloading. If hacker will get the token from the session, then the app will be insecure.

Comment: Don't let the hacker get the token then. Use httpOnly session cookie. Avoid XSS as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012109/adding-additonal-security-to-website/29015666#29015666

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan and what about  `implications on caching`? What it could be?

Comment: you would not be able to use http caching with token-per-request as every response would be different.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that in my case it is no more Synchronizer Token Pattern, but Double Submit Cookies Pattern instead. Am I right?